# which concepts learn in ANDROID JAVA for creating video editing timeline like kinemaster app

Tags: android, seekbar, timeline

hai sir i have a doubt please tel me answer

my doubt is which concepts learn in ANDROID JAVA for creating video editing timeline like kinemaster app  in android java programming:
[image]

[image]